# If Non-existence is nonexistent, then does that mean a Supernatural Exists?

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, theology, nothing, existence-of-god

Ok, what I am asking is bascially, if non-existence (which I use synonymously with the word 'nothing' - this is my defintion of 'nothing' in this piece - non-existence, so please no dcitionary warriors - I'm creating the defintions!) - does not exist, does that mean that a Supernatural Being must necesarily exist? The following is the thought process behind it.

First, let's define terminology for this question:

**Being** - with a capital B: Being is all that exists

*being* - with a small b, are entities that exist, and make up Being. The world is a being

**sub-beings** - Are part of beings. humans are sub-beings of the world

**Necessarily true/false** - a statement which logically must be true/false. If a statement is necessarily true, it must be impossibly false and vice versa.

**Impossibly true/false** - a statement which logically cannot be true/false

**Nature** - what constitutes a being. The nature of a being has an opposite

**Quality** - what describes a being. Qualities, e.g. colours, heights, weights, do not have opposites but are of degrees.

**Composite** - to be made up of parts; i.e. to be endlessly divisible

**Simple** - to be one; i.e. not made up of parts and unable to be divided

The thing that all of beings share as part of their nature is that they all exist. This is their fundamental nature. I.e. Being exists.

The opposite of Being is non-Being. I.e. The opposite of all that exists, is non-existence.

Non-Being cannot exist. **Non-existence cannot exist**.

**Non-Being cannot exist is necessarily true and impossibly false. In other words, nothing cannot exist.**

As non-Being cannot exist, that means Being, as its opposite, must exist unlimitedly:

1). It is unlimited in extension (space)
2). It is unlimited in duration (time)

That is, Being (Existence as a whole) extends unlimitedly in every direction. This is necessarily true and impossibly false. To claim Being is of a certain magnitude (e.g. a million miles long) indicates that it is limited. What can limit it? The only possibility is nothing, i.e. non-Being, which breaks the unlimitedness and creates a barrier to it. But non-Being cannot exist. As such, Being, by its very definition, must be unlimited. It cannot be measured. It just, is.

Being must also have always been and always will. It always existed. To say that the duration of Being began at some point again indicates the existence of nothing, of which, something (Being) then started to Exist. Nothing does not exist, and thus something cannot come from nothing. It also means that Being must always continue to exist, as something cannot turn into nothing, as nothing cannot exist.

Thus Being is unlimited in extension and duration (i.e. space and time) is necessarily true and impossibly false.

Does the World Exist Alone?

(I use the world as synonymous with universe throughout.) We know, as a necessity, that Being must exist unlimitedly in both extension and duration.

The next question therefore is, does the world/universe, exist alone? If so, does it constitute the whole of Being?

The world is a being. We are sub-beings of the earth, as is everything that is upon it; the trees, the animals, the air etc. Sub-beings make up being as a whole. That is, what is true for one sub-being is true for the whole of being, as a being is the sum of its parts. This means if we know about the fundamental nature of one sub-being, it tells us the fundamental nature of all sub-beings and thus the being they form, as a whole.

Let's take one sub-being. An apple. We can see clearly that the apple is limited in both extension and duration. That is, the apple does not extend unlimitedly - it is clearly limited to a size. It also changes during time; from a seed to ripeness to overripeness and decay. In other words, it does not stay the same; it changes due to time (duration).

We, as humans, also change over time. We are also limited in size - we can be measured; we are not unlimited. The world itself is limited - by taking a step north I am a step closer to America; by taking a step back I am a step further. Distance/space can be measured because it is **limited**.

The fundamental nature of the world is that it is composite. That means it is endlessly divisible. That means, we can keep breaking the world down into its constituent parts, and we continue this process endlessly.

The world is limited as it is composite; that means we can take from it and add to it. E.g. we can cut the apple in halve and take halve away. Or we can glue onto it another apple, making it bigger.

How do we know however, that the world is actually composite and endlessly divisible? How do we know that rather than being composite - that is, being made up of a substance which is endlessly divisible, it is actually made up of simple, non-composite particles which exist side-by-side to one another?

This is easy to address. If the world was made of simple particles next to one another, those particles would need a substance to separate them. However, any substance between them would in fact be proof of compositeness- the substance would join, not separate. The only thing that can separate two simple entities/particles is a barrier of nothing. However, nothing does not exist. This means that two simple entities/beings cannot exist together, as there would be no way to separate them as nothing does not exist. Anything that separated them would have to be a substance and thus the whole part would actually be a composite being.

Thus we now know that two or more simple beings cannot exist together and this necessarily true and impossibly false.

This means we have a dilemma. We know the world, and thus the whole universe (as the world is a being to us, but a sub-being in the universe) is composite and thus limited. Yet, Being is unlimited.

How can this be the case? There are three possibilities:

1). Being (all that exists) = The world is the whole of Being
2). Being = A simple being exists next to a composite world (I.e. Simple being + the world)
3). Being = The world is contingent upon a simple being

We know that 1) is not true as the world is limited. We know 2) is impossible as a simple Being cannot exist next to any other being, simple or composite, as this will imply the existence of nothing which is necessarily false and impossibly true.

The only other option is that a simple being exists upon whom existence of the world is contingent (i.e. the world's existence depends upon the existence of this simple being). For the purposes of examination, let us call this simple being, the Supernatural.

Attributes of the Supernatural

**Simple**
The Supernatural MUST be simple. That is, the Supernatural cannot be made up of parts. The Supernatural must be unlimited in extension and unlimited in duration. This is necessarily true and impossibly false.

**One**
The Supernatural must be one. This is necessarily true and impossibly false. There cannot be more than one simple being as this would imply that nothing exists.

**Immutable**
Immutable; i.e. unchangeable. A simple being of unlimited extension and duration cannot change. Change is only a quality of that which can be taken from or added to, i.e. something which is composite. As time is really just parts of a duration (e.g. a second is a part of a minute, a minute of an hour etc) it also only applies to the composite. I.e. the Supernatural must be unchangeable.

**Omniscient and Omnipotent**
The Supernatural is Simple. Thus, It cannot take from Itself in order to make something else (this is only a quality of composite beings - e.g. seeds from plants and childbirth etc). Thus the way It Creates is purely from Its will. If It simply wants something to be, it is. This is the definition of  Omnipotence.

The Supernatural has always been and always was and always was been. It willed the world into existence.

Prior to the world there was only the Supernatural, the composite world did not exist. This means that the Supernatural is able to perceive itself and the opposite of itself, and it is able to create from this. Thus, it knows everything and is thus Omniscient.

Where is the World?
The world is contingent upon the Supernatural. The question, 'Where is the world?' is thus meaningless. As the Supernatural is unlimited in extension, it has no magnitude and so direction and location do not apply to it. The world is contingent upon it (the world cannot exist without the Supernatural's existence) and thus the question actually refers to the Supernatural and not the world, and as the Supernatural is unlimited, it cannot apply to it.

Can 'God' Create Another of Himself?
Again, the answer is meaningless. Written another way, the question is,
"Can God Create an uncreated Being?" The answer is made clear in the question.

Comment: In what sense "Non-existence is nonexistent"? Usually, we assert *existence* of something"; what "thing" is non-existence?

Comment: "Being is unlimited in extension and duration (i.e. space and time) " This means that space and time are prior to existence and Being? If so, they are Non-Being, and thus non-existenet.

Comment: See [Spinoza](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spinoza/): the world is the whole of Being **and** the only Being is God.

Comment: “Being” is all that exists. If this is interpreted as the set of all things that exist, and Being exists, then “Being” is a set that contains itself. This is not an outright contradiction, but it will create problems and lead to very unintuitive conclusions. If “Being” is not a collection of all that exists, then I don’t know what it could be.

Comment: You will need a definition for “unlimited”. Its use here is inconsistent and is leading to conclusions that are not necessarily true. There can be (and evidence suggests there are) limits to space and time. The universe is believed to be finite and about 14 billion years old. It did not exist forever. In a “Big Crunch” scenario, the universe will end as well, in finite time.

Comment: Unlimited is simply that which is not limited.

Comment: ‘Non-existence’ of a ‘thing’ is just obtrusive wordplay. 

Being indeed means existence. I’d say don’t focus too much on finding fault with the words chosen in the definition I’ve given - (as explained elsewhere re dog and cat), but rather on the argument itself which actually I don’t find anyone really commenting on…

Answer (score 0):

> As non-Being cannot exist, that means Being, as its opposite, must exist unlimitedly

That non-Being cannot exist follows from the meaning. However, it is at least logically possible that nothing had existed (subjunctive mood, i.e., counterfactual statement). So, your claim that non-Being is your definition of "nothing" seems fallacious on the face of it. Maybe you mean it is your definition of nothingness, but nothingness is just the logical case where there would be nothing, so we're back the fact that your "non-Being" is not the same as nothing or nothingness.

Further, it does not follow from the fact that non-Being cannot exist, that Being must exist, let alone that Being exists, let alone that Being exists "unlimitedly".

The existence of Being is as empirical fact. Each of us knows that there is something, at least this is what people would usually say. So there is something, so it is not true that there is nothing.

And that is pretty all there is to say on this point.

> Being, as its opposite, must exist unlimitedly: 1). It is unlimited in extension (space) 2). It is unlimited in duration (time)

Whatever there is is obviously limited to itself. We usually call the whole of what exists "reality", and reality, whatever it is, is necessarily limited to itself. So Being is limited to itself, so they claim that it is unlimited seems also fallacious.

Space and time are part of reality (Being), so it does not mean anything to say that  Being is unlimited in space and time. Take a checkboard. It comprises black and white squares. A checkboard is not limited to either black or white squares but it is limited to black or white squares, so it is limited. Suppose it is a checkboard infinite in extension. It would still be limited to black or white squares. For example, it would have no red or green squares.

So, your reasoning is not founded.

The whole piece is essentially wishful thinking. Perhaps you could think about spending your time more productively. Time is in not unlimited. Think about it

Comment: I’ve defined a word to be used as I have defined it. But instead you decided to define it as something else. If I said, ‘i have chosen to use the word ‘cat’ to mean what we usually call a dog in the English language’ then ‘cat’ in my piece would indicate a dog. There’s no use arguing that it’s ‘a dog’ because the name i’m giving it for the purpose of the piece is ‘cat’. That’s what I meant re: dictionary warriors. But it’s the first thing you launched into re: nothing

Comment: Re: check board and colours. It’s limited because it has squares….the squares are limited. A whole is the sun of its parts - thus the chess board analogy is incorrect - it cannot be unlimited/infinite in extension due to the fact it is made of limited squares. Infinite by the way, is a process not a product. Ie in your example, we can add chess board squares infinitely (ie endlessly) but each time we did so we would end up with a certain number of squares. We can continue the process infinitely adding more squares, but at each juncture, will have a limited number of squares.

Comment: @Simon With the infinite checkboard, I think they meant something isomorphic to the [module](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_(mathematics)) ℤ², which is in fact infinite, as its underlying set has cardinality ℶ₀. I'm not sure what you mean by "[i]nfinite by the way, is a process," since that's not how that word is usually understood.

Answer (score 0):

It’s utterly logical that if ‘nothing’ does not exist, then Being (that is, existence), must be infinite/unlimited.

On a lexical point re: space and time you are correct in saying (which I think you are), that such terms would only really apply to what is limited ie what can ne measures - which is exactly what I wrote later on in the piece. For ease of understanding unlimitedness, I used extension & duration to help create some kind of visual, while the more correct term would simply have been ‘unlimited’ and that’s it.

As I mentioned in comments above, ‘infinite’ would technically be an incorrect term as it refers really to a process, of which the unlimited is not a part of.

You actually haven’t found a flaw in the argument…you’ve just picked on the word ‘nothing ’ incorrectly and given a  mistaken analogy with a limited chess board which can’t extend unlimitedly as it is limited.

Comment: Welcome to SE Philosophy! Thanks for your contribution. Please take a quick moment to take the [tour](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/tour) or find [help](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help). You can perform [searches here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search) or seek additional clarification at the [meta site](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/). Don't forget, when someone has answered your question, you can click on the arrow to reward the contributor and the checkmark to select what you feel is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. "Nothing" does not name a thing. Tigers are things and do exist; unicorns would be things, were they to exist, but they do not exist. "Nothing," however, does not name a thing. "Nothing exists" seems true only because its meaning has not been understood. "Nothing exists" only means "Not anything exists." Nothing neither exists nor fails to exist, and similarly nonexistence neither exists nor fails to exist, because neither "nothing" nor "nonexistence" names a thing.
2. "Non-Being does not exist" does not imply "Being exists." Neither "non-Being" nor "Being" names a thing, which could either exist or fail to exist (like a tiger or a unicorn).
3. Assuming space to be limited in extent, that would not imply that there was some "nothingness" "outside" of space. Perhaps limited space is simply all there is, with no "outside" at all.
4. Again, assuming the past to be limited--assuming there to be a beginning of the universe--would not imply that there was a "time before the universe began," for perhaps going back to the beginning is simply all the time there was. "Before the beginning" seems oxymoronic.

I wish I could quote your post and then reply piecemeal!

Anyway, it looks as though you're following Heidegger, and Heidegger, I'm afraid, will only confuse you.